# Concat json data inside for loop

Tags: json, pandas, python-requests

I have a number of tickers and I need to get the full quote information. I used a `for` loop to get through the tickers and called `requests.get()` on each ticker. I need to append the ticker quote to the main `DataFrame()`, and used `concat()` to append each ticker.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for symbol in get_earnings.head(5):
    url = f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{symbol}?apikey={api_key_3}'
    data = requests.get(url)
    response = data.json()
    dx = pd.DataFrame(response)
    df = pd.concat([df, dx], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    if len(df) > 1:
        df.to_csv('data/latestEarnings.csv')
```

I get this error
`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

The output of the `response = data.json()` from each ticker which I need to append to the main `DataFrame()`

```
[{'symbol': 'RSKIA', 'name': 'George Risk Industries, Inc.', 'price': 13.1, 'changesPercentage': 4.8839, 'change': 0.61, 'dayLow': 12.49, 'dayHigh': 14.1, 'yearHigh': 14.1, 'yearLow': 9.81, 'marketCap': 64191703, 'priceAvg50': 12.2656, 'priceAvg200': 11.74125, 'exchange': 'PNK', 'volume': 6498, 'avgVolume': 406, 'open': 12.49, 'previousClose': 12.49, 'eps': 1.35, 'pe': 9.7, 'earningsAnnouncement': '2024-03-15T10:59:00.000+0000', 'sharesOutstanding': 4900130, 'timestamp': 1710781859}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing:

```
dx = pd.DataFrame(response)
```

to:

```
dx = pd.DataFrame([response])
```

Also note that your two last lines are with a wrong indent. They should be outside the loop.